# Can't delete rows containing certain keyword within text

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro to remove rows containing certain text in it. If either of the keyword contains any text, the macro will delete the row. However, the macro doesn't work at all. Perhaps, i did something wrong in it. Hope somebody will help me rectify this. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I'm trying with:

```
Sub customized_row_removal()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 2
    Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "mth" Or "rtd" Or "npt" Then
            Cells(i, 1).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The keyword within the text I was searching in to delete:

```
AIRLINE DRIVE OWNER mth
A rtd REPAIRS INC
AANA MICHAEL B ET AL
ABASS OLADOKUN
ABBOTT npt P
AIRLINE AANA MTH
ABASS REPAIRS NPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.
What about Using Lcase.

```
Sub customized_row_removal()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngU As Range, rng As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count))
    End With

    For Each rng In rngDB
        If InStr(LCase(rng), "mth") Or InStr(LCase(rng), "rtd") Or InStr(LCase(rng), "npt") Then
            If rngU Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU = rng
            Else
                Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee, it works great for lower case. What about upper or mix cases? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry  Dy.Lee, for my ignorance. The text within inverted comma has to be written in lowercase, as in "mth" not "MTH" that I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

VBA syntax of your `Or` is wrong,

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value = "mth" Or "rtd" Or "npt" Then
```

Should be:

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value = "mth" Or Cells(i, 1).Value = "rtd" Or Cells(i, 1).Value = "npt" Then
```

**However**, you need to use a string function, like `Instr` or `Like` to see if a certain string is found within a longer string.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub customized_row_removal()

Dim WordsArr As Variant
Dim WordsEl As Variant
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet

WordsArr = Array("mth", "rtd", "npt")

Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With Sht
    ' get last row in column "A"
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        For Each WordsEl In WordsArr
            If LCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Like "*" & WordsEl & "*" Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next WordsEl
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai Rado, for your answer. Your macro works partially. however, two major things it can't handle. 1. can't touch those cells which contains the same keyword with mixed case or upper case. 2. I applied it on 500 cells. Upon first run it deletes 20 then again when i run it deletes another 10 and so on until all of them containing the keyword.

Comment: I tried just now but the rectified code doesn't work at all

Comment: @Shahin  could be a little more specific and help, what doesn't work ? Are you getting an error? What is the value of lastRow when you run in debug mode ?

Comment: Just get back to you.

Comment: Lastrow has correctly been identified by your macro. No error thrown upon running your macro, no result either.

Comment: @Shahin  what is he name of your sheet ? The words you want to check are in column A, right ?

Comment: Sheet1. Yep it is in column A. Sorry i was away.

Comment: @Shahin try edited code (worked for me), make sure your data is in "Sheet1"

Answer (score 0):

**I try to make my code sample as I can if you have any question please ask**

```
  Private Sub remove_word_raw()
'PURPOSE: Clear out all cells that contain a specific word/phrase

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ContainWord As String

'What range do you want to search?

  Set Rng = Range("A2:A25")

  'sub for the word

   shorttext1 = "mth"
   shorttext2 = "rtd"
   shorttext3 = "npt"
'What phrase do you want to test for?

  ContainWord1 = shorttext1
  ContainWord2 = shorttext2
  ContainWord3 = shorttext3

'Loop through each cell in range and test cell contents

  For Each cell In Rng.Cells
  If cell.Value2 = ContainWord1 Then cell.EntireRow.Delete

     Next
     For Each cell In Rng.Cells
     If cell.Value2 = ContainWord2 Then cell.EntireRow.Delete

     Next
     For Each cell In Rng.Cells

      If cell.Value2 = ContainWord3 Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
      Next cell
End Sub
```